# On isolated points of the approximate point spectrum of a bounded operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a complex Banach space and $T$ be a bounded operator acting on $X$.
Let $\sigma(T)$ and $\sigma_{ap}(T)$ denote the spectrum and approximate point spectrum of $T$, respectively.

Let $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$. It is classical that, with the aid of the spectral projection, $\lambda$ is isolated in $\sigma(T)$ if and only if $T - \lambda$ can be decomposed as a direct sum of a quasinilpotent operator and an invertible one.

Now my natural question is as follows:

Let $\lambda \in \sigma_{ap}(T)$. Is it true that $\lambda$ is isolated in $\sigma_{ap}(T)$ if and only if $T - \lambda$ can be decomposed as a direct sum of a quasinilpotent operator and a bounded belowness one?

Here we say that an operator is bounded below if it is injective and its range is closed.

It is also nature to find the answer for other spectra (eg. left spectrum, surjective spectrum, right spectrum, essential spectrum,...).

Thank you!